# SQL query merging two queries or any other method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1- users table 
2. friends_table

The `users_tbl` columns are

```
user_id int primary key, user_name text
```

The `friend_tbl` columns are

```
sender_id references users_tbl (user_id) int, 
receiver_id int references users_tbl (user_id), 
is_accepted bit
```

I need a query for a specific `@user_id` and it needs to return all the users without the `@user_id` joining the `friends_tbl` column.

Example the tables with data:

**users_tbl** :

```
user_id    user_name
----------------------------
    1      tarik 
    2      alex
    3      frank
```

**friends_table** :

```
sender_id    receiver_id   is_accepted
--------------------------------------
    1            2              0
```

Input

```
user_id =1
```

Output

```
user_id    user_name    is_accepted
------------------------------------
    2      alex               0
    3      frank           NULL
```

I'm using this in mvc a function gets a user id and returns a table of all users joining the `is_accepted` column specific for the incoming `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the all user information from user table without the parameter user.
Left join with friends table and get the is_accepted column data.

```
Declare @users_tbl table
(
    user_id int primary key, 
    user_name varchar(100)
)

Declare @friend_tbl table
(
    sender_id int, 
    receiver_id int, 
    is_accepted bit
)

insert into @users_tbl values(1,'tarik')
insert into @users_tbl values(2,'alex')
insert into @users_tbl values(3,'frank')

insert into @friend_tbl values(1,2,0)


Declare @userId int = 3

Select u.user_id, u.User_name, f.is_accepted from @users_tbl u
    Left Join @friend_tbl f on u.user_id = f.receiver_id AND f.sender_id = @userId
    Where u.user_id != @userId
```

Comment: thanks for the reply  , but i  did try this method it didnt get the result i want if u put the @user_id=3 it will returns--> alex  0        wich is not what i need , i need it to be null because this user has no friends request  between him and @user_id , thnaks

Comment: @TarikHusin, I have added a new condition `f.sender_id = @userId`. Now Its working for both input.

Comment: @TarikHusin If it works, can you make as answer and mark this answer as useful.

Comment: okay i will ,  but i have another question if the @user_id =2 the is_accepted should be 0 with the user 1  because there is a friend request between him and 1